# Chained hash table implementation to store student's information

Tags: c, hash-map

This is my implementation of a Hash Table to store information about a student. Everything seems to work as expected, but I'd like some feedback on the following:

- Is my style good? Is it easy to read the code? Could i do better job naming variables? If so can you give examples?
- Would your implementation of a hash table for this propose be much different than mine?
- In the real world of programming, are hash tables used that much? I'am diving into linked lists and trees soon, they seem to be better data structures.

---

```
/**
 *
 * Uses hash table
 * to store information
 * about students
 * Id, name and final grade
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_LEN 80 + 1

// struct with student information. id, name and final grade
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    int finalGrade;
}
Student;

// Struct containing a pointer to Student and size of the "list" in a hash position
typedef struct
{
    Student* family;
    int size;
}
Hash_Unit;

// hash function uses id of student and table size
int Hash(int key, int N)
{
    return (key % N);
}

Student* CreateStudent();
Hash_Unit* CreateTable(int N);
void InsertStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, Student newStudent);
void RemoveStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, int id);
int SearchStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, int id);
void ListTable(Hash_Unit* Table, int N);
int ReadFile(const char* file, Hash_Unit* Table, int N);
void PrintStudent(Hash_Unit *Table, int N, int id);
int SaveAsFile(const char* file, Hash_Unit* Table, int N);

int main()
{
    int option, tableSize = 10, studentID, searchIND;
    char file[20];
    Student* auxStudent;
    Hash_Unit* Table;

    Table = CreateTable(tableSize);

    do
    {
        printf("------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("Type 0 to quit.\n");
        printf("Type 1 to insert student.\n");
        printf("Type 2 to remove student.\n");
        printf("Type 3 to take look at student.\n");
        printf("Type 4 to search for a student.\n");
        printf("Type 5 to list all students.\n");
        printf("Type 6 to read file and load hash table.\n");
        printf("Type 7 to save hash table to a file.\n");
        printf("Option: ");
        scanf("%d", &option);
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                auxStudent = CreateStudent();
                InsertStudent(Table, tableSize, *auxStudent);
                free(auxStudent);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("Insert id of student to remove: ");
                scanf("%d", &studentID);
                RemoveStudent(Table, tableSize, studentID);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("Insert id of student: ");
                scanf("%d", &studentID);
                PrintStudent(Table, tableSize, studentID);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Insert id of student to search: ");
                scanf("%d", &studentID);
                searchIND = SearchStudent(Table, tableSize, studentID);
                printf("Student is at position %d in hash table list\n", searchIND);
                break;
            case 5:
                ListTable(Table, tableSize);
                break;
            case 6:
                printf("Enter name of file please: ");
                scanf("%s", file);
                ReadFile(file, Table, tableSize);
                break;
            case 7:
                printf("Enter name of file please: ");
                scanf("%s", file);
                SaveAsFile(file, Table, tableSize);
                break;
            default:
                if (option != 0)
                {
                    printf("Invalid option.\n");    
                }
        }
    }
    while(option > 0);
}

Student* CreateStudent()
{
    Student* newStudent;
    newStudent = (Student *)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    if (newStudent == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    printf("ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &newStudent->id);
    printf("Name: ");
    scanf("\n");
    fgets(newStudent->name, NAME_LEN, stdin);
    printf("Final Grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &newStudent->finalGrade);
    return newStudent;
}

Hash_Unit* CreateTable(int N)
{
    Hash_Unit* Table;
    Table = (Hash_Unit* )malloc(N * sizeof(Hash_Unit));
    if (Table == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for(int i = 0;i < N; i++)
    {
        Table[i].size = 0;
        Table[i].family = (Student* )malloc(0 * sizeof(Student));
        if (Table[i].family == NULL)
        {   
            printf("No memory.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return Table;
}


void InsertStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, Student newStudent)
{
    int pos, auxSize;
    pos = Hash(newStudent.id, N);
    auxSize = Table[pos].size + 1;
    Table[pos].family = (Student *)realloc(Table[pos].family, auxSize * sizeof(Student));
    if (Table[pos].family == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory.\n");
        return;
    }
    Table[pos].size = auxSize;
    Table[pos].family[auxSize - 1] = newStudent;
}

void RemoveStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, int id)
{
    int i, pos;

    pos = Hash(id, N);
    i = SearchStudent(Table, N, id);

    for(; i < Table[pos].size - 1; i++)
    {
        Table[pos].family[i] = Table[pos].family[i+1];
    }
    Table[pos].size -= 1;
    Table[pos].family = (Student* )realloc(Table[pos].family, Table[pos].size * (sizeof(Student)));
    if (Table[pos].family == NULL)
    {
        printf("No memory.\n");
        return;
    }
}

// return index of a student in a list. returns -1 if not found.

int SearchStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, int id)
{
    int pos, i = 0;
    pos = Hash(id, N);
    if (Table[pos].size == 0)
    {
        printf("No students found.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while ((Table[pos].family[i].id != id) && (i < Table[pos].size))
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i == Table[pos].size)
    {
        printf("Searched all list. Didn't find it\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return i;

}

void ListTable(Hash_Unit* Table, int N)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (Table[i].size > 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Table[i].size; j++)
            {
                printf("Table position: %d\n", i);
                printf("ID: %d\n", Table[i].family[j].id);
                printf("Name: %s", Table[i].family[j].name);
                printf("Final Grade: %d\n\n", Table[i].family[j].finalGrade);
            }
        }
    }
}

int ReadFile(const char* file, Hash_Unit* Table, int N)
{
    FILE *f;
    Student newStudent;
    f = fopen(file, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("error: ");
        return NULL;
    }
    while (fscanf(f, "%d\n", &newStudent.id) > 0)
    {
        fgets(newStudent.name, NAME_LEN, f);
        fscanf(f, "%d", &newStudent.finalGrade);
        InsertStudent(Table, N, newStudent);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 1;

}

void PrintStudent(Hash_Unit *Table, int N, int id)
{
    int pos, familyPosition;
    pos = Hash(id, N);
    familyPosition = SearchStudent(Table, N, id);
    printf("Hash Position = %d\n", pos);
    printf("family Position = %d\n", familyPosition);
    printf("ID = %d\n", Table[pos].family[familyPosition].id);
    printf("Name = %s", Table[pos].family[familyPosition].name);
    printf("Final Grade = %d\n", Table[pos].family[familyPosition].finalGrade);

}

int SaveAsFile(const char* file, Hash_Unit* Table, int N)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(file, "w");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        perror("error: ");
        return -1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (Table[i].size > 0)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Table[i].size; j++)
            {
                fprintf(f, "%d\n", Table[i].family[j].id);
                // does %s printf \n?
                fprintf(f, "%s", Table[i].family[j].name);
                fprintf(f, "%d\n\n", Table[i].family[j].finalGrade);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hash tables are commonly used because of their speed--searching takes on average constant time, whereas trees take logarithmic time, and linked lists searching takes linear time.  That said, try including a way to resize your hash table; the table's speed is a result of few collisions, i.e. entries going to the same bucket in the table.

Comment: I like your coding style, but your comments sort of lost steam a quarter of the way through. Your variables and function names are descriptive enough that this isn't really a problem, but a couple of comments in the functions that explain how you are implementing them would go a long way. Keep up the great work!

Comment: Your first define should be 81, not 80 + 1.

Answer (score 2):

### Returning error values but not checking them

Your code does something good which is return error values such as `-1` for "not found" or `NULL` for "out of memory".  The problem is that the callers of those functions don't check the return values.  So for example, if called `RemoveStudent()` with a student ID that didn't exist, it would get here:

> ```
> i = SearchStudent(Table, N, id);
>
> for(; i < Table[pos].size - 1; i++)
> {
>     Table[pos].family[i] = Table[pos].family[i+1];
> }
> ```

`SearchStudent()` would return -1, and then you would end up indexing `Table[pos].family[-1]` because you didn't check the return value.  You can easily make your program crash by just entering an invalid ID when you search for a student using option "3".

Also I noticed that `ReadFile()` is supposed to return an int, presumably 0 for success and -1 for error.  But it actually returns 1 for success and NULL for error.  That triggered a compiler warning when I compiled your program because NULL is not an int.

### Malloc 0 bytes

When you create your hash table, you do this:

> ```
>     Table[i].family = (Student* )malloc(0 * sizeof(Student));
> ```

I would just do:

```
    Table[i].family = NULL;
```

because `realloc()` later will behave properly with a NULL argument.  It's implementation dependent as to what `malloc(0)` actually does.

### Reallocation strategy

The way you reallocate each hash bucket by extending its length by 1 will cause you to use \$O(n^2)\$ time, where \$n\$ is the length of the hash bucket.  You should think about doubling the size of the hash bucket instead.  This will require you to use two variables instead of just one: `size` and `maxSize`, to track the current slots in use and the total slots allocated.

Here is how `InsertStudent()` would look with the new scheme:

```
#define INITIAL_SIZE        2

void InsertStudent(Hash_Unit* Table, int N, Student newStudent)
{
    int pos  = Hash(newStudent.id, N);
    int size = Table[pos].size;

    if (size >= Table[pos].maxSize) {
        if (Table[pos].maxSize == 0)
            Table[pos].maxSize = INITIAL_SIZE;
        else
            Table[pos].maxSize *= 2;
        Table[pos].family = (Student *)realloc(Table[pos].family,
                Table[pos].maxSize * sizeof(Student));
        if (Table[pos].family == NULL) {
            printf("No memory.\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    Table[pos].family[size] = newStudent;
    Table[pos].size++;
}
```

I would recommend that `RemoveStudent()` not call `realloc()` at all, and just reduce `size` by 1.

### Variable names

I suggest using lowercase names for variables.  If you just look at the color coding that StackExchange applied to your code, it colors variables like `Table` as if they were type names.  It's probably because of the unwritten assumption that type names are capitalized and variable names are lowercased.

### fgets() leaves the newline

The names that you read using `fgets()` all have newlines in them.  You need to strip the last character of each name if it is a newline.  This is why in your `SaveFile()` function, you had this question:

> ```
>             // does %s printf \n?
>             fprintf(f, "%s", Table[i].family[j].name);
> ```

It's because your name already had a newline, so you didn't have to add one.  Normally you would do this:

```
             fprintf(f, "%s\n", Table[i].family[j].name);
```

### Extraneous if

In this code:

> ```
> for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
> {
>     if (Table[i].size > 0)
>     {
>         for (int j = 0; j < Table[i].size; j++)
>         {
>             printf("Table position: %d\n", i);
>             printf("ID: %d\n", Table[i].family[j].id);
>             printf("Name: %s", Table[i].family[j].name);
>             printf("Final Grade: %d\n\n", Table[i].family[j].finalGrade);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

You don't need the if statement.  The `j` loop will not iterate once if the table size is 0.  You did this in a couple of places.

### Use parentheses around macros

This macro is dangerous:

> ```
> #define NAME_LEN 80 + 1
> ```

You need to put parentheses around it like this:

```
#define NAME_LEN (80 + 1)
```

Otherwise, if you do something like this:

```
x = NAME_LEN * 2;
```

With your macro, `x` would be 82 instead of the proper 162.